# Third-Party Cookies in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, lti, canvas-lms, third-party-cookies

On the latest version of Chrome (Version 90.0.4430.85 on MacOS), I found that **third-party cookies are disabled** even though in my browser settings I checked "Allow all Cookies". I also tried adding the site to "Sites that can always use cookies" and checked "Including third-party cookies on this site", but it still doesn't seem to work. I'm accessing a course on LTI that requires third-party cookies. (The course is quite old so that might be an issue)

I'm getting this error:
[image: error]

Chrome Settings:
[image: chrome settings]
[image: chrome settings 2]

The reason I know this is because my other laptop has an earlier version of Chrome(around 80) and the cookies are working(the course loads), but it no longer works when I update my Chrome to the latest version.

When I tried in Safari, I'm able to allow third-party cookies by disabling "Prevent cross-website tracking", but I cannot find such settings in Chrome.

Any ideas on what I might try to be able to use third-party cookies on the latest version of Chrome? Also, why is it the case that this site functions in an earlier version of Chrome but not the latest? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case you need the link to the course I'm accessing: https://canvas.instructure.com/courses/785215/assignments/2233109?module_item_id=4761765 (it's a publicly available course for anyone with a Canvas LMS account)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your browser settings for 3rd-party cookies look OK as far as testing by allowing all.

The issue may be with the LTI tool/app provider who is providing their product through Canvas and other LMS's - for example, if the LTI tool/app provider hasn't set their cookies with `SameSite=None` - sounds like you're suspecting that as far as course/app being older.

I think you can test this by temporarily disabling the same site requirement here: chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies

There are a few other decent testing tips from Chromium [here.](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug#TOC-Something-is-broken----Debugging-tips)

If that's the issue and you still need to provide access quickly for a bunch of users, but can't wait for the LTI tool/app to be updated, you can usually update the LTI app/tool settings in Canvas to open it in a separate tab/window instead of as an iframe - e.g. [these settings in Canvas.](https://community.canvaslms.com/t5/Developers-Group/How-do-I-make-a-LTI-External-Tool-link-on-a-Page-open-in-a-new/td-p/210113)

Hope it works out!

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Disabling the same site by default in Experiments worked perfectly.

Comment: You could install your own site, although might be quicker to sign up for a Canvas trial account or you can try Moodle's demo site - https://sandbox.moodledemo.net/